# Laravel route group displays 404 page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, controller, routes

I have route group and able to display the index page but when I tried to access the other route it returns 404 page not found. What am I missing here?

**Route:**

```
Route::group(array('domain' => env('CLUBSITE1')), function () {
    Route::get('/', '\App\Http\Controllers\Club1\IndexController@index');
    Route::get('/news', '\App\Http\Controllers\Club1\IndexController@news');
});
```

**Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Club1;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
class IndexController extends Controller {

    public $data;

    public function index() {
        return view('clubs.home');
    }

    public function news() {
        return view('clubs.news');
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you register namespace in composer ?

Comment: Maybe club.news contains a 404 page. :) What is the HTTP status code, 404?

Comment: @systemovich yes it's 404

Comment: There is an artisan command for checking the registered routes. I think it is `php artisan route:list`. See if `/news` is there in the URI column and that it has an Action.

Comment: command displays [ReflectionException] Class App\Http\Controllers\IndexConttoller does not exist (IndexConttoller), so i've change it to IndexController but it displays same error but know it says IndexController

Comment: I do see know the /news in route list it's present

Comment: What you mean `change it to IndexController`?

Comment: I mean some Controllers were misspelled  as IndexConttoller

Answer (score 0):

If you want to separate directories between controllers, you can do it like this:

```
Route::group(['domain' => env('CLUBSITE1'), 'namespace' => 'Club1'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index');
    Route::get('/news', 'IndexController@news');
});
```

There is a debug method to determine what causes the problem:

```
Route::group(['domain' => env('CLUBSITE1'), 'namespace' => 'Club1'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index');
    Route::get('/news', function() { return 'hello, world'; });
});
```

Then send a request to `/news`, if you see `hello, world` indicates your project configuration cause the problem, if not indicates your code causes the problem.

Comment: I've tried it but it still returns "404 Not Found Requested page not found!"

Comment: And then excute `php artisan route:list` to see routes you defined

Comment: running the artisan command displays [ReflectionException]                                      
  Class App\Http\Controllers\IndexConttoller does not exist  (IndexConttoller), so i've change it to IndexController but it displays same error but know it says IndexController

Comment: I do see know the /news in route list it's present

Comment: Did you try the debug method i mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to access via "index.php/news"?

If it works, then it's .htaccess problem.

Comment: I'm using nginx